# Session expiring when redirecting to URL

Tags: java, spring

It seems that when I attempt to call a URL with ModelAndView(), my session is ended and when the view is loaded, a new session is created without any of the data I hope to persist.

```
     return new ModelAndView("redirect:http//.....)
```

Is there a better way to handle sessions besides @SessionAttributes when moving to different controllers?

Comment: Session is session--unless it's HTTP v. HTTPS, in which case under some servers you need to indicate the two protocols should share sessions. You don't provide much info to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@SessionAttributes` session objects are not meant to be shared among controllers. Here are some alternatives:

You can store attributes directly into HttpSession object. You can obtain HttpSession object by adding it to controller method as parameter:

```
public ModelAndView myControllerMethod(..., HttpSession session) {
  ...
  session.setAttribute("someAttribute", someValue);
  ...
}
```

You can also autowire HttpSession object and then use it in controller methods:

```
@Autowired
private HttpSession httpSession;
```

You can create a session scoped bean and inject that bean into controllers that need it:

```
<bean id="mySessionDataBean" class="com.example.MySessionDataBeanImpl" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy />
</bean>
```

And then use it in controllers (MySessionDataBeanImpl implements SessionDataBean interface in this example):

```
public class MyController {
    ....
    @Autowired
    SessionDataBean sessionDataBean;

    @RequestMapping(...)
    public ModelAndView controllerMethod(...) {
         ...
         sessionDataBean.setSomeValue(someValue);
    }
}
```